# How to get token value of string type from rest response

Tags: rest, delphi

Delphi 10.4.2

REST server generates new tokens every 2-3 hours and client must login in order to get new token. In Swagger and Postman server returns `HTTP 200`:
Response of server is uuid string like `"d14e02b7-ae5e-11ed-8105-005056b4f1d1"`

I create new `query` parameters on page "Parameters" of Rest Debugger. Server returns `HTTP 200` but in the tab "Tabular data" if I click on the `value` caption to select root element and then press "Apply" button get error:

> Response RootElement, "value",  is not a valid path for the response JSON.

If I place rest components(RecsClient, RestRequest, RestResponse, RestAdapter) on the form and RootElement property of RestResponse is set to 'value' or 'resultData' I get the same error.

But if I empty RootElement property of RestResponse component and execute RestRequest component I get `HTTP 200` and token value appears in FDMem component but how then from RestResponse extract uuid **single string** value?

[image: login1]

[image: login2]

[image: login3]

**SOLUTION:**

this code works:

```
var token:String; 
token:=RestResponse1.JSONValue.Value;
```

or this:

```
var
  JV: TJSONValue;
  str1,str2: string;
 begin
  str1:= fRefGoods.rrespLogin.Content;  
  JV:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(str1);
  str2:=JV.Value;
```

the confusion was caused by not knowing that "d14e02b7-ae5e-11ed-8105-005056b4f1d1" is a valid JSON-string. I thought it was necessary JSON-string be enclosed in {} curly brackets and data presented as JSON-Pairs separated by commas. As it turned out I was wrong.

JSONLint also identifies it as valid JSON-string.

Comment: The response is valid JSON but is a single string. Looks like the root element is `string`. Not sure if Delphi Rest Debugger supports this however.

Comment: That JSON is only valid as per [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-2) from 2017, but not as per [RFC 4627](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627#section-2) from 2006. In the latter/older standard JSON must be an object or array, so a string only would have been invalid. The REST Debugger is correct according to the old standard, but wrong according to the newer. In doubt, let the server send `{ "hash": "4543-453..." }`.

Comment: Also: you can press `Ctrl+C` in a dialog to get its context=text copied into the clipboard - you don't have to re-type it and make grammar mistakes like "_responce_" and "_roor_".

Comment: @AmigoJack  response is uuid string in double quotes like "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111". There are no root element in response. How get returned string from response if didn't exist root element? I tried str:= rrespLogin.RootElement.DeQuotedString but RootElement didn't exist. Then I tried str:=RESPResponse.JSONValue as TJSONObject or restresp.Getvalue('value').ToString but without success.

Comment: That has little to do with your question, because you now talk about code, not the REST Debugger anymore. Sure you don't want to edit your question? Because in Delphi you could just take your response (which is a String anyway - it's irrelevant if it contains a UUID or a GUID or whatever) and enclose it in other Strings so it then looks like my example, which makes it "valid" as per 2006 standard, and which you then can get parsed.

Comment: @AmigoJack If RootElement property of Restresponse component is empty then after I  execute Restrequest component in 'content'  property of Restresponse component I see result like "1111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111".  Is this  json string? If this is json string how extract  value if  there are not pair but single string? I am not able to use JsonResponse.getvalue(' ') as I don't know  returned string' name to use in getvalue. If I use FdMemTable I get Restresponse in it and may use it but how extract single json string direct from json, not from FDMemTable?

Comment: @AmigoJack Finally, this code works:  var TOKEN:String; TOKEN:=RestResponse1.JSONValue.Value;